# Google Analytics (Universal) event tracking not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-tracking

I am running the following code (on document ready) to try to get google analytics event tracking working. The hitCallback is being run as expected, but the events are not being shown in Google Analytics.

```
$(function() {
console.log('pushing event');
ga('send', {
    'hitType': 'event1',         
    'eventCategory': 'button',
    'eventAction': 'click', 
    'eventLabel': 'contact form',
    'hitCallback' : function () {
        console.log('event received');
   }
});
});
```

This code is currently live on http://atmosfire.com.au/.

In Google Analytics / Real Time / Events, I can see 1 active user (me), but none of the events I am triggering are being logged.

[image: Analytics Screenshot]

Help?

Comment: open the network panel in the console, and run the function. See if it is triggering a request from the browser first.

Comment: ^^ make sure you see the actual event being sent to GA in the request. Also, real time only shows basic stuff at first like page views. You need to wait a bit to see things like events or custom vars. Even though GA collects it all at the same time, different things take different amounts to show up in the reports (even real time reports) based on a number of factors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that "event1" is a valid hittype. Hittype can be any one of event, page view, social, transaction, item, exception, screen view, or timing.

Comment: Ha! Woops, I added the 1 when mucking around/debugging and forgot to remove it. Whatever the original issue was seems to be resolved. Thanks.